CKEditor skipping html tags and CSS classes
I am integrating Ck-editor 5 in html but it is not supporting html DIV tags and CSS classes. I put some code with div with the source menu but it skips the DIVs.
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/39.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>

my code is
<script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
                toolbar: {
                    items: [
                        'heading', '|',
                        'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'link', '|',
                        'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|',
                        'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', 'fontSize', '|',
                        'alignment', '|',
                        'insertTable', 'blockQuote', '|',
                        'undo', 'redo'
                    ]
                },
                fontColor: {
                    colors: [
                        { color: '#000000', label: 'Black' },
                        { color: '#444444', label: 'Dim Grey' },
                        { color: '#888888', label: 'Grey' },
                        { color: '#CCCCCC', label: 'Light Grey' },
                        { color: '#FFFFFF', label: 'White', hasBorder: true },
                        { color: '#FF0000', label: 'Red' },
                        { color: '#FFA500', label: 'Orange' },
                        { color: '#FFFF00', label: 'Yellow' },
                        { color: '#008000', label: 'Green' },
                        { color: '#0000FF', label: 'Blue' },
                        { color: '#800080', label: 'Purple' }
                    ]
                },
                fontSize: {
                    options: [
                        'tiny', 'small', 'default', 'big', 'huge'
                    ]
                },
                htmlSupport: {
                    allow: [
                        {
                            name: 'div',
                            attributes: true,
                            classes: true,
                            styles: true
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'span',
                            attributes: true,
                            classes: true,
                            styles: true
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'p',
                            attributes: true,
                            classes: true,
                            styles: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            })
            .then(editor => {
                console.log('Editor was initialized', editor);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    </script>

I want to keep HTML tags like DIVs and etc. how to handle this or provide me code example. I also have tried with allowedContent = true but unfortunately unsuccessful.
Note: please don't mark the question already asked or close the question, the questions already asked are very old may be of 2015. and I have tried that too.
